# vim setting 'map<F12> :!python %<cr>' automatically return to vim after executing in terminal

Tags: vim

I added `map<F12> :!python %<cr>` into `~/.vimrc`. However, it automatically quit after executing this command, when I pressed the key `<F12>`. In normal case, it should stop at a line `Press ENTER or type command to continue`, but in my case, it just skip this line and return to vim. It looks like someone press ENTER Secretly. The most surprising thing is that it only happen in terminal. when I type `:!python % ' manually or use gvim, everything is OK. I have no idea how to fix this problem.

Comment: Same problem here, I have absolutely no idea. Besides, sometimes Vim doesn't even execute my commands. Sometimes it helped me, to put a `print` into my python code somewhere.

Comment: @DavidHalter A moment age, I suddenly find the truth. The command I added have an unexpected trailing space. so when `Press ENTER or type command to continue` appeared the vim add a space automatically...

Comment: @Yyao I still have the same problem, I don;t even have any trailings space. Exact syntax `map <F7> :!python %<CR>`

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that the terminal version is redrawing the screen before you are able to read the message. You could try setting `'lazyredraw'` to delay the redraw.

A workaround can be setting `'lazyredraw'` and adding a call to function `getchar()` to the mapping:

```
  function! RunPython()
     let s:save_lz = &lazyredraw   " save 'lazyredraw' setting
     set lazyredraw
     !python %
     call getchar()                " stop waiting pressing a key
     let &lazyredraw = s:save_lz   " restore 'lazyredraw'
  endfunction
  map <F12> :call RunPython()<CR>
```

---

EDIT:

You may also consider using a plugin for this task, as ["SingleCompile : Make it more convenient to compile or run a single source file"](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3115).

Comment: Thank you very much. The plugin is a very nice plugin. Just now I found that the reason is the command I added have an unexpected trailing space incautiously.