# Vim command window output closes automatically when the key mapped to :mark<CR> is pressed

Tags: vim, command, shortcut

So this is what I have

```
nnoremap M :marks<CR>       " show marks
```

If I manually type the command and press enter, it shows up fine. Also other commands that does not have "Press Enter or type command to continue" works fine. But it does not work when I press <kbd>M</kbd> in normal mode.

I thought this behavior might have to do with `shortmess+=A`, but that was not it either. Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069963/vim-setting-mapf12-python-cr-automatically-return-to-vim-after-executin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim's interpretation of Ex commands is different from most other languages, that's why this is a common pitfall. A check with `:nmap M` would have shown you that the comment is included in the mapping.

You could work around this here by concluding the mapping with the `|` command concatenator (that why you have to use `<Bar>` to include such into the mapping):

```
:nnoremap M :marks<CR>|       " show marks
```

You could have also used `:execute` (the typical solution to this kind of problem), but here the best way probably is to just move the comment to a separate, preceding line.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is the trailing spaces. I should be careful not to add spaces and comments when I am doing remapping.

```
nnoremap M :marks<CR>
```

fixed the problem. Notice no comments and spaces after `<CR>`